# Spring error handling

Tags: json, spring, exception, controller

i need to catch all exceptions of my controllers to a exception controller. How to configure spring?
I need this because every request to my webapp are json request and in case of exception i need to answer with a genericc {success: false, exception: "String ex..."}. But i can not understand if the better way is to use SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a custom response, it would be more interesting to use a custom [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) implementation.

spring configuration:

```
<bean id="exceptionHandler" class="com.am.CustomHandlerExceptionResolver"/>
```

java:

```
public class CustomHandlerExceptionResolver
    implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        //write in response
        return null;
    }

}
```